# To comunicate with arduino should I use C# or Java?

Tags: java, c#, android, bluetooth, arduino

I got an Arduino Uno and a Bluetooth module HC-6 and I intend to make a smartphone with android comunicate with it and then pass the information for a desktop's program to process and return the result to the arduino and then to the smartphone again

Which one should I choose to build my desktop program, Java or C# (I'd like to work with one of them) ? I read that C# is easier to do it

(My Android App is already being developed)

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Comment: Both are possible, you could even use C# for all your stack (W10 IoT on Arduino, C# on desktop and Mono with Xamarin for Android), so it's up to you. And since it's only a matter of personal preference, it's off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a command line interface with python, but I know you would prefer C# or java. If you want to make a graphical interface use java, but I do not know much about C#, only C++. if they are alike with the libraries, then use C# for a command line interface like on linux.

first answer on stack overflow, hope I did OK, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Try both and use the one you like, I like C# because most of my work is around for Windows 7 or above and I love Visual Studio + Resharper.